# can't run react scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

npm log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~prestart: learny-frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: learny-frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: 
PATH:     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-            bin:/Users/hassnianidrees/Desktop/projects/learny-
  frontEnd/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/usr/local   /share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Command   s:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
9 verbose lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/hassnianidrees/Desktop/projects/learny-frontEnd
10 silly lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle learny-frontend@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: learny-frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid learny-frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/hassnianidrees/Desktop/projects/learny-frontEnd
16 verbose Darwin 19.0.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error learny-frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the learny-frontend@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**T'm trying to install this project and i'm getting this error i'm pretty sure that the project is ok bcz it worked when I did make the commit.**

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install` before `npm start` ?

Comment: yes i did , deleted node_modules and lock.json and installed again and nothing same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use YARN package manger.

Yarn installations procedure - [Link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable)

then install the package using it